# How to merge two columns as per third column (ID) in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have dataframes in following format:

```
dataframe 1 : ID     income              dataframe 2: ID      income
              2        23                             1          14
              3        12                             4          20
              5        13                             6          17
```

How to merge these two dataframes in pandas so that the resultant dataframe is like:

```
result:  ID      income
         1          14
         2          23
         3          12
         4          20
         5          13
         6.          17
```

( As you can notice , the rows are inserted in between as per the IDS )

Comment: Some of the income values don't match their original IDs in your expected output. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `ID` is the index to the DataFrame:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'income': [23, 12, 13]}, index=[2, 3, 5])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'income': [14, 20, 17]}, index=[1, 4, 6])

>>> pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_index()
   income
1      14
2      23
3      12
4      20
5      13
6      17
```

If the `ID` is a column:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'income': [23, 12, 13], 'ID': [2, 3, 5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'income': [14, 20, 17], 'ID': [1, 4, 6]})

>>> pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True).sort('ID')
   ID  income
3   1      14
0   2      23
1   3      12
4   4      20
2   5      13
5   6      17
```